# Return Error code when using try and except? (without raise)

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except, error-code

I have some scripts running in docker containers that collect data from yfinance.
Sometimes crashes occur because the data is not available.

So I wanted to send me a mail if a crash occurs in a script, but I wanted it to be the exact error code that caused the main function to crash.

Is there a way that would allow me to return the exact error code as a variable (and send it per mail) instead of just using try and except?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        ERROR = 'Value Error occured in BOT1'
        print(ERROR)
        sendmail(ERROR)
        sleep_time(1800)
```

Comment: What exception are you catching in that except clause when the crash happens? Is the error code you want in that exception? There isn't enough information in your question to answer.

Comment: Look at `traceback.format_exc()` which will get you the exact cause of the crash in a string you can put in an email. You will still need a `try...except`, though. You want to catch the exception without halting execution, and the way to do that is `try...except`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] but I wanted it to be the exact error code that caused the main function to crash.

Try with the `except`/`as` syntax:

```
try:
    main()
except Exception as e:
    # here you can print e
```